# How do I properly encode values that I send to PayPal Payments Pro?

Tags: paypal

### Question

What's the correct way to send parameter lists to the PayPal APIs? Here's a concrete example of some parameters I'd like to know how to send correctly:

```
TRXTYPE               S
BILLTOSTREET          123 Marks & Spencer St.
CUSTREF               648=ZVC_Gxk
```

There is inconsistent documentation on the matter, and most code I've found on the web doesn't use the length-prefixing that PayPal describes (yet still seems to work!).

### Background

The [PayPal Payments Pro](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PayflowGateway_Guide.pdf) documentation describes their custom and non-standards compliant NVP format on p44 and surrounding pages. It is also contradictorily described on the [PayPal API NVP Basics](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_NVPAPIOverview) page  as "All requests to execute PayPal API operations sent using HTTP must be URL-encoded.".

The large PDF doc also contradicts itself:

- The "Name-Value Parameter Syntax Guidelines" section of the PDF states "Do not use spaces in values". However, it then presents an example of a "correct" NVP string that includes spaces in the BILLTOSTREET parameter.
- The "Name-Value Parameter Syntax Guidelines" section states "Enclose the NVP parameter string in quotation marks". Is this referring to the entire string of encoded values? Should my POST body look like the following, including quotes?  "TRXTYPE=S&TENDER=C..."
- It claims that the entire parameter string should be surrounded with double quotes.

Comment: From what i can tell these look like typical rules for a typical post i think if you jsut supply an array to cURL on `CURLOPT_POSTDATA` youll be good... or if you use `http_build_query`.

Comment: Which rules are you talking about, @prodigitalson? The PDF and the web page contradict each other. Also, I think you mean CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Thanks!

Comment: YEah i did.. i was talking about the NVP link you posted. Didnt look at the PDF.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I agree that the web page does describe standard encoding practices. However, the PDF doc describes an alternate encoding that has a length modifier on the key names ("KEY[4]") and explicitly states that values should not be URL encoded.

Comment: Only the values, not the parameters, need to be URL encoded. If you're using PHP, then `$url = "PARAM=" . urlencode($val) . "&ETC="`.

Comment: That seems to work for some parameters and not others. Two examples: (1) If you urlencode RETURNURL, Payflow will fail with a message saying something like "invalid URL". (2) If you have a field value that contains spaces or special characters, then the escaped strings will appear in the transaction history on manager.paypal.com (example: 123+Main+St.) rather than their canonical representation. Also interesting is that PayPal seems to set a "Content-type: text/namevalue" on responses, which is totally nonstandard.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the following works:

- URL-encode all values (but not parameter names)
- no quotation marks, neither for values nor for the whole post body

Btw, I've learned not to take Paypal's (horrible) documentation too serious but rather resort to trial and error, and SO...

Comment: Applying URL-encoding to RETURNURL, ERRORURL, etc causes requests to fail. URL-encoding values that appear in PayPal Manager (such as names and addresses) causes the encoded strings to appear in the reports.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the common server side languages (php, ror, java, .net) and would like to save time and effort simply use the appropriate PayPal's SDK https://cms.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks